# Playing short sound with SystemSound or AVAudioPlayer on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, audio, xamarin.ios, avaudioplayer

Creating custom spinner for iOS and for each rotation change need to play sound. Sound itself is 0.5 sec. According to Apple's documentation I used SystemSound to play it but now I can't control volume with hardware buttons cause audio context is Volume(media) and as I understood SystemSound works in different context, Ringer.

I tried to use AVAudioPlayer but there is a small delay when sound is attaching to the player and this glitches UI(small delay so spinner doesn't rotate smoothly).

Any ideas how this can be solved ?

I was thinking about somehow programmaticaly change this context by triggering controls that are working with systemSound, but no luck.

EDITED:
I've made sure that have only 1 instance of AVAudioPlayer and didn;t stop playing sound but paused it and only after spinner finished rotating then stop and dispose, but still same result

Comment: How does a playing sound glitch the UI?

Comment: Small delay so spinner doesn't rotate smoothly.